# jqueryui autocomplete with a header in prepend giving null reference when scrolling with keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery 1.11.1 and jqueryui 1.11.2.  The problem is appearing in windows 8.1 running IE.  The autocomplete uses "open" to prepend a header into the result set.  when you arrow down the first arrow down click will result in a "unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference.

So here is part of the autocomplete

```
 open: cComboboxOpenApplica,
 focus: function (event, ui) {//what populates the drop down
        $("[id$=txtApplicant]").val(ui.item.label);
        $("[id$=hfApplicantID]").val(ui.item.value);

        return false;
    },
```

and the function that is called by the open

```
function cComboboxOpenApplicant(event) {

var mComboboxOpenApplicant = '<li style="font-size:10px; padding-left:5px; padding-bottom:20px"><div class="divUIMultiColumnHeader" style="width:100px">First Name</div><div class="divUIMultiColumnHeader" style="width:150px">Last Name</div><div class="divUIMultiColumnHeader" style="width:50px">SSN</div><div class="divUIMultiColumnHeader" style="width:100px">ID</div></li></a>';
$("ul.ui-autocomplete").prepend(mComboboxOpenApplicant);
```

}

Again, this all works when I use the mouse.  When using the mouse if you mouse over the header row at the top of the returned results it does not hightlight that first line and does not allow you to click on it either.  If you use the keyboard and hit the down arrow once you get the error because it's trying to hightlight that first line that has the header in it and errors on

```
  focus: function (event, ui) {//what populates the drop down
        $("[id$=txtApplicant]").val(ui.item.label);
        $("[id$=hfApplicantID]").val(ui.item.value);

        return false;
    },
```

in the line ui.item.label

What am I missing to help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try event.preventDefault(); above your code in focus event.

like

```
focus: function (event, ui) {//what populates the drop down
        event.preventDefault();
        $("[id$=txtApplicant]").val(ui.item.label);
        $("[id$=hfApplicantID]").val(ui.item.value);

        return false;
    },
```

Comment: thank you for the response.  I tried what you suggested.. It does not appear to have made a difference.

Comment: @jvcoach23 Can you create a fiddle to replicate the problem?

Comment: Also I noticed at the end of your mComboboxOpenApplicant string, there's an extra </a>... there's no opening tag for it... @jvcoach23

Comment: I took some time to merge it into my Auto-complete fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e14kne1s/85/ ,seems to be working fine for me

Comment: I've also tried to put it into fiddle... but I can't use jquery 2.x.  also, fiddle does not have the version of jquery ui that I need.  the version that they have the mock up works.. i'm running jquery ui of 1.11.2.  Thanks for the effort though